# Adding radio buttons dynamically to a div using jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, dynamically-generated

I am burned out on this (may be due to Friday), I tried, googled but didn't find a way to make this thing work. the code looks straight forward, but it doesn't add the radio buttons to my div. I am sure, i am missing something silly.

```
var m_fastingOptions = [{ "Id": "1", "Name": "Fasting" }, { "Id": "2", "Name": "Not Fasting" }];

$.each(m_fastingOptions, function() {
    $("#dvFastingOptions").append(
        $('<label />', {
            'text': this.FastingName                            
        }).append(
            $('<input />', { 
                type: 'radio', 
                name: 'rdoFastingOptions', 
                id: 'rdoFastingOptions' + this.Id,
                value: this.Id
            } )
        )
    );    
});
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KXCtp/2/) that I was playing with. Any help is much appreciated.

After adding the correct jQuery version to jsFiddle, I see radio buttons but not the label text.

I need to see:
O Fasting   O Not Fasting

Comment: Your fiddle link isn't working :)

Comment: Try including jquery.  http://jsfiddle.net/DsQFn/  ... always check your console.  You would see that `$ is undefined`.

Comment: youre missing jQuery in your fiddle. after adding that its working :)

Comment: you need to add jquery on the jsFiddle

Comment: First step when something isn't working: Check your console. You would have immediately seen "_Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined_" and known that jQuery wasn't referenced.

Comment: Ok guys, thanks for that.. BUT I guess, the actual problem is yet not resolved for me. The label doesn't show me the text.

Comment: I deserve all the down-votes on this man. My bad. Going home now. You guys have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, you are referring to the wrong property name.

Instead of `Name`, you are trying to navigate to `FastingName`

```
$('<label />', {
    'text': this.Name //This is correct
})
```

Either that, or you update your object to be:

```
var m_fastingOptions = [{
    "Id": "1",
    "FastingName": "Fasting"
}, {
    "Id": "2",
    "FastingName": "Not Fasting"
}];
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/XWHsA/

**Edit:**

To see the output as

```
O Fasting O Not Fasting
```

use [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) instead of [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: Not my day today. It is one of the worst question I have ever asked on SO. I need to go home now. :((

Comment: that is so cool,but if I need to take an ID of a particular checkbox then `        $('input:radio[name=rdoFastingOptions]:checked').each(function(){var selectedValue=$(this).val()}
` use this

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found solution to the problem,
here is the answer code,

```
var listOfOptions = [{ "Id": "forYourself", "Name": "For Yourself" }, { "Id": "myEmployees", "Name": "My Employees" }, { "Id": "forOthers", "Name": "For Others" }];
        $.each(listOfOptions, function() {
            $(".optionDiv").append(
                $('<input />', {
                    type: 'radio',
                    name: 'rdoOptions',
                    id: 'rdoOptions' + this.Id
                })
            );
            $(".optionDiv").append(
                        $('<label />', {
                            'text': this.Name
                        })
            )

        });
    });
```

Any better simpller way to do this?